# Render different html elements based on the width of the parent container in react

Tags: css, reactjs

I have to display the logo text if the width of the parent div is greater than 125px and display the logo icon if the width of the parent div is less than 125px.

But in the whole process, the actual window is not resized.

CSS media queries can be triggered only during screen resize events. But in my case i have to trigger an event where the screen's size remains same and the width of a div changes.

I have added colors for better representation.

Initially search bar will be closed, i have enough space to display the logo text so i can display it.

[image: Search bar is closed]

But when I click on search icon search bar expands to a certain width and less space will available for logo text so i want to display logo icon.

Like this

[image: Search bar (red) is expanded]

Currently i have a variable searchBarActive which is set to true when the search bar is open and set to false when the search bar is closed.

```
function Navbar() {

  const [searchBarMobileActive, setSearchBarMobileActive] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <nav>
        {/* Navbar container */}
        <div className='nav-container'>
          {/* logo */}
          <div
            className={`logo ${searchBarMobileActive ? 'logo-icon' : ''}`}
          >
            <h4>{searchBarMobileActive ? <FaBirthdayCake /> : 'The Navbar'}</h4>   // This line is doing conditional rendering of logo text and logo icon
          </div>
        ...
```

But the problem with this approach is that when search bar is closed, searchBarMobileActive variable is immediately set to False. But the search bar closes with a small animation which takes some time, **as a result the parent container of logo is still small and the logo text appears and starts overflowing out of the container.**

Logo text immediately appearing and overflowing out of the container also overflows the search bar and pushes down

[image]

So i want to dynamically check if the width of the parent div is > or < 125px and do the conditional rendering instead of just relying on searchBarMobileActive state.

I tried to get the width of parent container using useRef, but since the component is not re-rendered when the width changes, seems like there is no way left.

Comment: Toggle your site logo on the search bar state, if its open then show icon and when it is close show your full logo image.

Comment: Yeah i was doing same, but the problem is the logo text was quickly snapping as a result it temporarily made the closing search bar overflow (last image). I fixed it by adding a small delay to show logo text as of now.